# How do I use a date range minus 1 year in MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

I'm creating a query in MSSQL (for SAP Business One) to compare sales and profit on a given date range (using between [date] and [date]) with the sales and profit for the same date range of last year, but I don't know how to do that.

I'm using the following code for the date range:

```
WHERE t1.docdate between '[%1]' and '[%2]'
```

thank you

Comment: `DATEADD(YEAR, -1, YourDateColumn)`

Comment: As @scsimon says (lol), use [DATEADD()](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/dateadd.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
dateadd(year,-1,[date])
```

[Add and Subtract Dates using DATEADD in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2509/add-and-subtract-dates-using-dateadd-in-sql-server/)

Be aware of the implications of using `between`, as shown here: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand - 2009-10-16](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I will read into it right away. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data for the same date range *last* year, you have two choices:

```
WHERE dateadd(year, 1, t1.docdate) between '[%1]' and '[%2]'
```

or

```
WHERE t1.docdate between dateadd(year, -1, '[%1]') and dateadd(year, -1, '[%2]')
```

Notes:

- In the first situation, you are *adding* a year to the date, not subtracting one.
- The parameters seem strange, but I'm not familiar with SAP formats.
- I strongly agree with Aaron about avoiding `between` with dates.  However, I'm leaving the logic as is because that is how the oP phrased the question.

Comment: it worked, thank you!